# Can't populate results from a website using vba

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I've created a script in vba using IE to get the content poputaled upon selecting an option from dropdown. In the site's landing page there is a dropdown named `Type`. When I click on `Type`, I can see few options there and I would like to click on `corporate bond` among them. When the result are generated I would like to parse the `WKN`.

I've tried to populate results using my current script by clicking on the dropdown and selecting an option from there. However, it clicks on the dropdown and select the desired option but can't produce any result in InternetExplorer.

***How can I populate and parse the result selecting an option from dropdown?***

My attempt so far:

```
Sub SelectItem()
    Const link = "https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/en/tools/product-search/bonds/"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument, post As Object, T As Date

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate link
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
    End With

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:15")
    Html.querySelector("#bsg-filters-btn-bgs-filter-3 .bsg-btn__icon").Click
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Html.querySelector("#bsg-filters-menu-bgs-filter-3 .bsg-scrollbox label[for='bsg-checkbox-3053']").Click
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Html.querySelector(".bsg-dropdown__footer button[type='button']").Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you click on the first field's [Close button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB4NF.png) with third `.querySelector`? I guess you need at least to specify the second found element: `Html.querySelectorAll(".bsg-dropdown__footer button[type='button']")(1).Click`. How does the entire web form being submitted should look like, each field?

Comment: Does this require login? The circles just keep whirring for me.

Comment: @QHarr It works without a login for me. There are currently 1413 results of Covered Bond type.

Comment: Nope, no login is required @QHarr.

Comment: :-( So the site just _hates_ me. Ah.... it hates my proxy. Sorted.

Comment: @QHarr Why not to try proxy or any anonymizer plugin?

Comment: That was a mistake @omegastripes. However, it should produce `9533 Bonds`.

Comment: It's my proxy it hates. Sorted now! Thank you.

Comment: @MITHU Is the "Covered Bond" the right type?

Comment: Nope, it would be `Corporate Bond`.

Comment: @MITHU The second `.querySelector("#bsg-filters-menu-bgs-filter-3 .bsg-scrollbox label[for='bsg-checkbox-3053']")` [points to Covered Bond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW0DL.png), seems you need to fix that also.

Comment: Right you are @omegastripes. Hardcoded time delay is a complete disaster also as it doesn't seem to be reliable. I didn't mention it in my post, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are familiar with timed loops so you can add timeouts to the following. I use css selectors through out to target elements. I monitor for the disappearance of the whirring circles as measures of page load at various points. At the end I monitor for presence of results items nodeList nodes.

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub GetCodes()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, btn As Object, items As Object, i As Long
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/en/tools/product-search/bonds"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Do
        Loop Until .document.querySelectorAll(".bsg-loader-ring__item").Length = 0


        .document.querySelector("#bsg-filters-btn-bgs-filter-3").Click
        .document.querySelector("#bsg-checkbox-3053").Click

        Set btn = .document.querySelector("#bsg-filters-menu-bgs-filter-3 .bsg-btn__label")

        Do
        Loop While btn.innerText = "Close"

        btn.Click

        Do
        Loop Until .document.querySelectorAll(".bsg-loader-ring__item").Length = 0
        Dim count As Long
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set items = .document.querySelectorAll(".bsg-table__tr td:first-child")
            count = items.Length
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While count = 0

        For i = 0 To items.Length - 1
            Debug.Print items.item(i).innerText
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I wasn't around to check @QHarr. Let you know how it behaved. A small token of thanks in advance.

Comment: Any problems let me know

Comment: Much appreciated.